# How to make a python package usable from terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal

I created an [open source python package](https://github.com/nidhaloff/deep_translator) to translate text or automate translations using different translators and published it on pypi. It is working great so far and I received some good feedback and criticism about it.

Now I'm not here to promote the project. Instead, I want to ask, how or what is the right way to make the package usable from terminal. Like in my example the project name is **deep_translator**. My goal is to be able to use it from terminal. Precisely something like this:

```
$ deep_translator translate --translator "google" --from "german" --to "english" --text="blabla"
```

I understand that if someone installs my package on his machine, the package will be likely added to the Path. Hence, it can be accessed from terminal but this must be depending on the OS, right?

So what is the right way to do this. I'm working with python>=3.6 but this is actually a general question and not python specific. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register a [command line script](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html) in your `setup.py` file. When the package gets installed this places a binary on the path, which invokes the configured function. For example:

```py
# setup.py

setup(
    ...
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': ['deep_translator=deep_translator.main_module:main_func'],
    }
    ...
)
```

Here `main_module` is a hypothetical module hosting a function `main_func` which will be invoked. In this function you can setup an [`ArgumentParser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser) and parse the arguments:

```py
# main_module.py

def main_func():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(...)
    # more arguments here
    args = parser.parse_args()
    # do stuff with args
```

#### Alternative: `__main__.py`

You can also use a top-level `__main__.py` module and then invoke your package via the `-m` switch:

```
python -m deep_translator <args-go-here>
```

Comment: I tried using argparse but it didn't worked. I get always this error no matter what I do: error: unrecognized arguments:

Comment: @basilisk Well you have to register all arguments that you plan to use via `add_argument`.

Comment: Thanks ;) I managed to get it working already but your answer was a great hint ;)